# Assume $\int_0^\infty f(x)dx$ converges. Prove there exists $\xi\in[1,\infty)$ such that $\int_1^\infty \frac{f(x)}x dx=\int_1^\xi f(x)dx$.

Tags: calculus, integration, mean-value-theorem

> Assume $\int_0^\infty f(x)dx$ converges. Prove there exists $\xi\in[1,\infty)$ such that $$\int_1^\infty \frac{f(x)}x dx=\int_1^\xi f(x)dx.$$

I used various mean value theorems but couldn't get the desired result. Another attempt beyond these is:

Let $\displaystyle F(x)=\int_1^x f(t)dt$, then
\begin{align*}
\int_1^\infty \frac{f(x)}x dx=\int_1^\infty \frac1x ~dF(x)&=\left.\frac {F(x)}x\right|_1^\infty-\int_1^\infty F(x) ~d\frac1x\\
&=0-0+\int_1^\infty \frac {F(x)}{x^2}dx\\
&=\int_1^\infty \frac {F(x)}{x^2}dx.
\end{align*}
How to analyze next? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Do we know that $f$ is positive? If the answer is yes, we can use the intermediate value theorem.

Comment: @1mdlrjcmed  No, the only assumption is $\int_0^\infty f(x)dx$ converges.

Comment: @1mdlrjcmed Of course, $f$ must be integrable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With your excellent notations denote by $M=\sup F(x)$ and $m=\inf F(x)$ which are finite since $F$ is continuous and $L=\lim _{x\to \infty} F(x)$ exists and is finite.  Then since $\int_1^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^2}dx=1$ we have $$m\leq I=\int_1^{\infty}\frac{F(x)}{x^2}dx\leq M.$$ If $I=m$ or $M$ then $F(x)\equiv m$ or $M$. If not there exists $x_0$ and $y_0$ such that $$m<F(x_0)<I<F(y_0)<M$$ and one applies the intermediate value theorem to the continuous function $F$ restricted to the interval $[x_0,y_0]$ or $[y_0,x_0]$ to claim the existence of $\xi$ such that $F(\xi)=I.$

Answer (score 3):

With the substitution $x = 1/t$ the problem is equivalent to showing that there is a $\eta \in (0, 1)$ such that
$$
 \int_0^1 t \cdot \frac{f(1/t)}{t^2} \, dt = \int_\eta^1 \frac{f(1/t)}{t^2} \,dt \, ,
$$
and that is exactly the statement of the [second mean value theorem for definite integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Second_mean_value_theorem_for_definite_integrals) for the increasing function $G(t) = t$ and the integrable function $\varphi(t) = f(1/t)/t^2$.